# Conditional using of CSS framework in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli, mean-stack, angular-template

I try to integrate a specific CSS framework (material-design) for my **Admin module** and another one CSS Framework for my **User module** in the same project application.

If it's possible how can I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use conditionnaly a specific bundle script depending to route.

The easiest way is to create one project by module.

Integrate your external component separately into your project.

Then to host your two projects on the same URL, you have to use a reverse proxy (For example : HAProxy). Or declaring one project by domain or sub domain.

Comment: thanks for shared your knowledge "each module can contain their own route". I need each module import different external theme like admin module in "admin-LTE" theme and user module "material.io" theme etc..

Comment: It's not possible to define a specific external component (js/css) by module because theses external  components are bundled  by angular-cli (webpack). You can use my solution 1 using 2 separated projects.